# PHP Header Function Redirect argument passing

Tags: php, redirect, header, hyperlink, arguments

I am new to PHP, so kindly bear me.
I want to redirect to some other page and pass multiple argument from header in PHP.I can pass one argument,but when i start adding more parameters it gives error.I think most probably there is something syntax error.But i can't get around it.Can you please advise on this.

This is when i have one argument it works fine.

```
  header('Location: ReservationConfirmation.php?confirmationNum=' . mysql_insert_id());
```

I want to add additional parameters here,but it gives error.Kindly advise.

```
header('Location: ReservationConfirmation.php?confirmationNum='. mysql_insert_id()'&dtTimeSlot='$dtTimeSlot'&iTheatreId='$iTheatreId);
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a few dots to concatenate the strings.

```
header('Location: ReservationConfirmation.php?confirmationNum='. mysql_insert_id().'&dtTimeSlot='.$dtTimeSlot.'&iTheatreId='.$iTheatreId);
```